# Converting ONNX model to Tensorflow Lite - pytorch_half_pixel not supported

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to convert my ONNX model to Tensorflow Lite format. Simple code but getting this error. I updated my onnx version with no luck

```
import onnx
import tensorflow as tf
import onnx_tf
#
#
# README: This file converts an onnx model to tflite
#
#
#

onnx_model_path = '/home/sfrye/segmentation/segmentation_checkpoints/efficientnet/modified-new.onnx'

onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_model_path)

tf_model = onnx_tf.backend.prepare(onnx_model)
tf_model.export_graph("tflite_model.tf")
```

Here is the error

```
RuntimeError: in user code:

    File "/home/sfrye/miniconda3/envs/mars_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/backend_tf_module.py", line 99, in __call__  *
        output_ops = self.backend._onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op(onnx_node,
    File "/home/sfrye/miniconda3/envs/mars_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py", line 347, in _onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op  *
        return handler.handle(node, tensor_dict=tensor_dict, strict=strict)
    File "/home/sfrye/miniconda3/envs/mars_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/handler.py", line 58, in handle  *
        cls.args_check(node, **kwargs)
    File "/home/sfrye/miniconda3/envs/mars_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/backend/resize.py", line 125, in args_check  *
        exception.OP_UNSUPPORTED_EXCEPT(
    File "/home/sfrye/miniconda3/envs/mars_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/common/exception.py", line 50, in __call__  *
        raise self._func(self.get_message(op, framework))

    RuntimeError: Resize coordinate_transformation_mode=pytorch_half_pixel is not supported in Tensorflow.
```

I tried updating my onnx as this fixed someones problem with this error code

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact same scenario, but I've solved a similar issue in the past by explicitly setting `interpolation=bilinear` in my `Upsampling2D` layers. Check any resize layers you have.
This would entail retraining the model though.